# Why is my javascript function failing?

Tags: javascript, html

What I want this code to do is display a button called Map. And above that some text should read "Chose a display". Then once that 'Map' button is clicked, it then displays a google map image through the  tags.

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Random</title>

</head>
<body>


<p align="center"style="font-family:verdana;"id="googlemap">
Choose a Display
</p>

<script>
function mapFunction()
{
x=document.getElementById("googlemap");  // Find the element
x.src="<iframe width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0"     marginwidth="0" https://www.google.com.au/maps?f=d&amp;source=s_d&amp;saddr=23+Burgundy+St,+Carseldine+QLD&amp;daddr=90+Gilbert+Rd,+Grange+QLD+to:Narrowneck+Court+Surfers+Paradise,+204+Ferny+Ave,+Surfers+Paradise+QLD&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=FfOeXv4d6qweCSn9XcBQSP2TazGVQ_0hH3aSYA%3BFRKQXf4d5_QeCSlRy4j_0lmRazEdtrkd8CRD0Q%3BFWXtVP4dWCUlCSGK90q-pKXOZCmv-18SewWRazGK90q-pKXOZA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=Narr&amp;sll=-27.422699,153.02411&amp;sspn=0.004819,0.008272&amp;t=h&amp;mra=ls&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=-27.555764,153.208466&amp;spn=0.584401,0.878906&amp;z=10&amp;output=embed"></iframe>;    // Change the content
}
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="mapFunction()">Map</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you mean to use `x.innerHTML='iframe stuff';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean `innerHTML`

```
var x = document.getElementById("googlemap");  // Find the element
x.innerHTML = '<iframe src="url here" ...></iframe>';
```

Since the HTML contains `"`, you can either escape them with `\` or just wrap the entire string with single quotes `'`.

Also, you forgot the `src` for the `iframe`.

Comment: There are a few more problems with the iframe tag, see my answer for a fixed string.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- You do not want to change the `src` of x, instead try modifying the `innerHTML`.
- Your iframe tag is both malformed (the URL should be prefixed with `src="` and there is no such thing as a `marginwidth` or `marginheight` attribute) and is not contained properly within the string (all dublequotes should be escaped `\"like this\"`)

So, this should work:

```
function mapFunction()
{
    x=document.getElementById("googlemap");  // Find the element
    x.innerHTML = "<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"480\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" style=\"margin-height:0;margin-width:0;\" src=\"https://www.google.com.au/maps?f=d&amp;source=s_d&amp;saddr=23+Burgundy+St,+Carseldine+QLD&amp;daddr=90+Gilbert+Rd,+Grange+QLD+to:Narrowneck+Court+Surfers+Paradise,+204+Ferny+Ave,+Surfers+Paradise+QLD&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=FfOeXv4d6qweCSn9XcBQSP2TazGVQ_0hH3aSYA%3BFRKQXf4d5_QeCSlRy4j_0lmRazEdtrkd8CRD0Q%3BFWXtVP4dWCUlCSGK90q-pKXOZCmv-18SewWRazGK90q-pKXOZA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=Narr&amp;sll=-27.422699,153.02411&amp;sspn=0.004819,0.008272&amp;t=h&amp;mra=ls&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=-27.555764,153.208466&amp;spn=0.584401,0.878906&amp;z=10&amp;output=embed\"></iframe>";    // Change the content
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A **p**-element can never have an src-attribute. Or you create the iframe with an empty src value / or you use **x.innerHTML** to write the iframe in.

As others said before, you need to \"escape the quotes\"

Answer (score 0):

It's because, one you need to use `innerHTML` , and two, you need to not close your quotes when setting `innerHTML`

```
x.innerHTML='<iframe width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com.au/maps?f=d&amp;source=s_d&amp;saddr=23+Burgundy+St,+Carseldine+QLD&amp;daddr=90+Gilbert+Rd,+Grange+QLD+to:Narrowneck+Court+Surfers+Paradise,+204+Ferny+Ave,+Surfers+Paradise+QLD&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=FfOeXv4d6qweCSn9XcBQSP2TazGVQ_0hH3aSYA%3BFRKQXf4d5_QeCSlRy4j_0lmRazEdtrkd8CRD0Q%3BFWXtVP4dWCUlCSGK90q-pKXOZCmv-18SewWRazGK90q-pKXOZA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=Narr&amp;sll=-27.422699,153.02411&amp;sspn=0.004819,0.008272&amp;t=h&amp;mra=ls&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=-27.555764,153.208466&amp;spn=0.584401,0.878906&amp;z=10&amp;output=embed"></iframe>';
```